# Best way to build a Javascript Array of Objects on Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have this but I'm pretty sure that is not the best way to build it up.

```
var dogs = {
  'names' : ["a", "b", "c"],
  'images': [
  <% @dogs.images.each do |image| %>
  {
    'thumb' : '<%= image.thumb %>',
    'medium' : '<%= image.medium %>',
  } <%= "," unless(@dogs.images.last.id == image.id) %>
  <% end %>
  ]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/ I'm too rusty to have the syntax correct here :)

Comment: what is `@dogs`, is it a model object?

Comment: yes, it is an active record model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't use just convert the images to a json object like:

```
var dogs = {
  'names' : ["a", "b", "c"],
  'images': <%= @dogs.images.to_json %>
}
```

You could also overwrite the to_json method in your model to exclude certain methods you don't want to display.

You can see how to overwrite to_json here:

http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2008/05/19/quick-example-of-serialisation-via-to_json-in-ruby-on-rails/